# Factorial code coverage

Tags: testing, recursion, code-coverage

In testing a recursive function such as the following factorial method; is it necessary to test the default case?  If I pass in 3 the output is 7 and code coverage reports show 100%.  However, I didn't explicitly test factorial(0).  What are your thoughts on this?

```
public class Factorial
{
  public static double factorial(int x)
  {
    if (x == 0)
    {
      return 1.0;
    }
    return x + factorial(x - 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code coverage doesn't tell you everything. In this case you'll get 100% line coverage for `factorial(3)` but it won't cover all "cases".

When testing a recursive function you'd want to test various cases:

- Each of the base cases.
- The recursive cases.
- Incorrect input (e.g., negative numbers).
- Any function-specific edge cases.

You can test less but you'll leave yourself open for potential bugs when the code is changed in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your input Simeon, I'd up vote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation . . . . yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically if you test[well, execute] factorial(2)  you also test [execute] factorial(1) *if* your algorithm is correct.

How would your testing tool know that your code was correct?  How would a tester that didn't write the code know your code was correct?  The point of "test coverage" is to determine that in fact as much of the code has been tested [well, executed] regardless of whether it is algorithmically correct or not.

*A line not executed is a line for which you have no evidence it works*.  This is what test coverage tells your.   The purpose of your tests is to check that the application *computes the correct answer*.  Coverage and tests serve two different purposes.  Coverage just happens to take advantage of the fact that tests exercise code.